# Why is my HTTP POST request by PHP cURL not working?

Tags: php, curl, http-post, php-curl

I am trying to make a very simple HTTP POST request via cURL. If you check the code below, `var_dump()` of `$output` gives full page along with error `You are not allowed to use or change the URL in that manner.`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$url = "https://businesssearch.sos.ca.gov/CBS/Detail";
$data = array(
    '__RequestVerificationToken' => $llc__RequestVerificationToken,
    'SearchType' => 'LPLLC',
    'SearchCriteria' => 'DW CAL 301 HOWARD LLC',
    'SearchSubType' => 'Keyword',
    'filing' => '',
    'enitityTable_length' => 10,
    'EntityId' => '201821910198'
    );
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($handle);
var_dump($output);
curl_close($handle);
```

I can confirm to you that I am getting the correct value for `$llc__RequestVerificationToken` everytime.

Sorry if this is confusing. You can mirror the process by going [here](https://businesssearch.sos.ca.gov/CBS/SearchResults?filing=&SearchType=LPLLC&SearchCriteria=DW%20CAL%20301%20HOWARD%20LLC&SearchSubType=Keyword) and then clicking on link 'DW CAL 301 HOWARD, LLC' in the table. That opens a new [page](https://businesssearch.sos.ca.gov/CBS/Detail). When I look at the HTTP Headers of this second page, it shows the following form data submitted:

```
__RequestVerificationToken: hv5r2HtDvn3KHzhpWcYRP2HQlgsiOgDPnnaDj9J8jlONxGNhzhdjlfzhDOXqSdJaYmcmiJRwc83s0-QuWC06o7xWSic1
SearchType: LPLLC
SearchCriteria: DW CAL 301 HOWARD LLC
SearchSubType: Keyword
filing: 
enitityTable_length: 10
EntityId: 201821910198
```

Only `__RequestVerificationToken` changes everytime but I successfully get it in my variable `$__RequestVerificationToken`, the rest of the information stays the same.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Much thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Once it is solved, I will remove the links and specific data from  the question to make it timeless and universal.

Comment: try `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $data ) );`

Comment: @Paolo I am still getting the same error.